# Merge out of sync feature branch with unsolvable conflicts to master

Tags: git, git-branch

I know this probably should never happen :(  but the reality is I have a `master` branch has some initial features of a smoke test, which is currently live on a site to for real clients to testing. Then the team plans to adds more features to the smoke test. I have been actively working on the new feature branch, let's call it `feature-branch`.

The `feature-branch` requires auth and more complex logic than master. I couldn't sync `feature-branch` with `master` while developing on it as updates on `master` will auto-deployed to live testing and we don't want to do that until the security is perfect.

Now the `feature-branch` is pretty much ready, however, the extra features caused dramatically changes on the code. I plan to merge this `feature-branch` to `master` to deliver the features added.

I expect there will be huge amount of conflicts, some of which would be hard to resolve. Luckily the major conflicts are only in a couple of files.

Is there a way to ***"overwrite"*** the `master` branch with this `feature-branch` while we keep the previous commit records of `master` branch?

Comment: I suggest that you pull the master branch to your feature-branch, resolve possible conflicts. At this point you can make a pull request or simply push your feature branch to the master.

All,your previous commit on the master branch will still be present. VCS are meant for that

Comment: @Bristol I think you should post this comment as an answer since it clearly and concisely answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you pull the master branch to your feature-branch, resolve possible conflicts. At this point you can make a pull request or simply push your feature branch to the master. All,your previous commit on the master branch will still be present. VCS are meant for that

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It helped a lot. Do git merge origin/master first, then resolve all possible conflicts. The feature branch can be safely merged into master after all confilicts are addressed.